# Multiple stacked chart

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, charts

I'm trying to reproduce this kind of chart:

[image: target bar]

So a bar chart with some stacked bar and some non stacked.

The closest I come by is this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fooMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
barMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)

ind = list(range(len(fooMeans)))

p1 = plt.bar(ind, barMeans, align='edge', width= 0.4)
p2 = plt.bar(ind, fooMeans, align='edge', width= 0.2)
p3 = plt.bar(ind, barMeans, bottom=fooMeans, align='edge', width= 0.2)
p4 = plt.bar(ind, fooMeans, align='edge', width= -0.2)

plt.xticks(ind, ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))
plt.yticks(range(0, 81, 10))


plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0], p3[0], p4[0]), ('Foo', 'Bar','Fii', 'Fuu'))


plt.savefig('foo.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Which draws this:

[image: closest bar]

That's not so bad but the x ticks are not aligned (probably because of the align='edge' of the bar) and the width trick that I use to show the bar next to each other (and not draw all the bar one on top of another) kind of look like an hack, is there any cleaner, by the books way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I find a cleaner way.

The best seems to play with the x position list (ind in my previous code sample).
So I've come up with a little function that can handle it for me:

```
def make_indice_list(indices, bar_number, bar_width, spacing_ratio=0):

    # "Center" the bar number around 0, not clear but if you have 3 bar, 
    # bar_number_indices = [-1, 0, 1]
    bar_number_indices = [i - int(bar_number/2) for i in range(bar_number)]

    indices_list = []
    for number in bar_number_indices:

        indices_list.append([ ( ((number* bar_width) + (spacing_ratio*bar_width) * number) + ind) for ind in indices])

    return indices_list
```

And I do this to use it:

```
indice_list = make_indice_list(ind, 3, 0.2, 0.1)
p1 = plt.bar(indice_list[0], barMeans, width= 0.2)
p2 = plt.bar(indice_list[1], fooMeans, width= 0.2)
p3 = plt.bar(indice_list[1], barMeans, bottom=fooMeans, width= 0.2)
p4 = plt.bar(indice_list[2], fooMeans, width= -0.2)
```

No more center, nor weird width, you just have to use the same indices for the stacked bar (and consider them as one when calling the function).

Wich, at the end, draw this:

[image]

You could probably make some improvement for the make_indice_list function, mostly removing the comprehension list and using numpy list but I think that's a sweet solution to me.